# Self.NavigationController = null in tableview?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

In My App I Create Everything Dynamically and i Create `TabBar` with First Tab (`TableView`) 
i wanna Navigate When Pressing in Cell And I Write This Code In `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

      TripDetailView * TripDetailViewObjec = [[TripDetailView alloc]initWithNibName:@"TripDetailView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:TripDetailViewObjec animated:YES];

}
```

And `self.navigationController=null` 
any help please ?

Comment: Do you have a `navigationController` defined anywhere? Like in you `AppDelegate`?

Comment: Are you using UITabBarController as root view controller of application? If yes, then viewControllers of tabbar controller must be UINavigationControllers.

Comment: UITabBarController Is Not a root View Controller of Application

Comment: i have NavigationController defined in appDelegate

Comment: and when i use [Self PresentModalViewController ] It Give Me Exception  that view Outlet is not set and i set it in IB ?

Comment: i Fix Problem With Navigation =null 
but there is anther problem that view outlet not set ? any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The navigation will not occur,because there is no `navigationController` within the first Tab.For navigation to take place you need to embed navigation controller over your TableViewController.try the following to embed the `navigationController` within the firstTab's TableView

in appDelegate.m

```
 - (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application { 

    UINavigationController * firstNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:yourTableViewController];

    // temporarily just used one tab

//tabBarController should be already connected through NIB

    [tabBarController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:firstNavigationController,nil]];

    self.window.rootViewController = tabBarController;
    }
```

Comment: i already make this .
problem now is Exception about view outlet is set to nil .
an the View Referencing Outlets is like this 
View-> TripDetailView 
any help please